# Multiple usage of many Mysqli prepared statements or lesser amount of direct queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My database has a table for user statistic and I cant find right way to select changed fields after update. Right now I select unknown amount of columns in one query with a function.

The question is what will be better/faster to use: 
Multiple prepared statements that will be executed one by one with different field:

```
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT amount from achievement_list where field=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$query_field);
foreach($fields as $field){
   $query_field=$field;
   $stmt->execute();
   //some actions
}
```

or all of those fields with one direct query:

```
$con->query("SELECT amount from achievement_list where field in($field_list)");
//some actions
```

Both ways can be used multiple times. So its a choice between many prepared statements or way less direct queries

Comment: Without seeing any other information, you should opt for the single query version, because it avoids many roundtrips to and from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There is no such question.

Prepared queries are **no different** from direct ones. The number in both cases is **exactly the same.**

So **you are just using prepared queries 100% of time** in case at least one variable is used in the query. Period. Nothing to discuss here.

And yes, *running a single query is faster than running multiple*.

Your particular question fits here as well. Just run **a single prepared query** like this

```
$in = str_repeat('?,', count($fields) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT field, amount from achievement_list where field in($in)"
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$types = str_repeat('s', count($fields));
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$fields);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $statement->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: That's an interesting misunderstanding but i call a field in my table `field` it holds the field used in the user statistic table to track, well, stuff. In both cases those are values. And im pretty sure that prepared statements are cached by mysql so its better to use with multiple executions. So number of queries is the same but the first one will be executed several times when the second one will execute just once. The question is what is faster for mysql.

Comment: Well, like you have been told, a single query is better than multiple. Yet, like you have been told,  there is no reason to use a direct query still. You can always use a single prepared query with IN clause as well

Comment: i cant use prepared statement there because the amount of that list is dynamic. Is there a way to use it with unknown amount of parameters?

Comment: Yes, you can create a list of placeholders dynamically as well

Comment: I prepare statement outside of my updating function that can be fired multiple times during one script, so i dont think i can use placeholders. And if it will be inside it'll become a different statement each time function is fired leading to not caching it, doesn't it?

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it answers all your questions.